# how can I run different command according to the result of last command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For example, there are 4 files (A,B,C,D) which I was try to upload with cURL, but sometimes it failed. My script is like this:

```
for f in `ls`
do
  curl -T $f ftp.server.com
done
```

A,B,C were uploaded successfully, while D left with some kind of errors. What I want to do is to remove A,B,C and keep only D in the directory.

Comment: I think you mean ``for f `ls` ``, not ``for files in `ls` ``.  But as sarnold says, it should be `for f in *`.

Answer (score 7):

First things first, you've coded a bug into your little script:

```
for files in `ls`
```

This should read:

```
for files in *
```

The difference is that `ls` approach won't properly handle files with whitespace in their names:

```
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold   15 2011-11-23 01:25 bad file
drwxr-xr-x 2 sarnold sarnold 4096 2011-11-21 03:07 blubber
$ for f in `ls` ; do echo === $f === ; done
=== bad ===
=== file ===
=== blubber ===
$ for f in * ; do echo === $f === ; done
=== bad file ===
=== blubber ===
$
```

Now, onto the upload-and-remove issue:

```
for f in * ; do curl -T $f ftp.example.com && rm $f ; done
```

The `&&` is a short-circuit operator; it will execute the second command only if the first command returns an exit value of `0` (which normally means "successful" in process return values -- yes, a little backwards). You might also someday find the `||` operator useful, to execute programs if something has failed. And perhaps most surprising, you can use them both on one command to do something on success or failure as appropriate:

```
$ true && echo success || echo failure
success
$ false && echo success || echo failure
failure
$
```

Comment: Thank you for your instruction with so much patient，it really helps me a lot !

Answer (score 3):

`$?` [refers to the return code](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html#sect_03_02_05).  Assuming "0" indicates a successful `curl` upload, then you want something like this:

```
for files in `ls`
do
    curl -T $f ftp.server.com
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
      rm $f
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I'll try your method as well,